# Fibonacci sequence long[] array throws negative numbers after index 92

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I'm testing this code to insert the Fibonacci sequence in a long[] array:

```
public class Test {
    public static void Fibonacci(int n){
        long[] array = new long[n];
        array[0]=1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (i==1) {
                array[i]=i;
            }
            else {
                array[i] = array[i-2] + array[i-1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(array[n-3]+"    "+array[n-2]); // verify sum
        System.out.println(array[n-1]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Insert Fibonacci sequence index: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        Fibonacci(n);
    }
}
```

However, after position 92, it starts throwing wrong or negative numbers. I'm using this [Fibonacci Calculator](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibCalcX.html) to verify the numbers and until 92 it's correct.
I've seen some questions here about this problem and most answers say its about Integer overflow, and that you should use long, which I am using.

Is 93th number over the limit of long type? What should I use instead to reach 100 or bigger numbers and still manage it with an array?

Comment: **Overflow**. Use a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overflowing the range of `long`. You can use `BigInteger` (and extract `array[1]` from the loop); something<sup>**1**</sup> like

```
public static void fibonacci(int n) {
    BigInteger[] array = new BigInteger[n];
    array[0] = array[1] = BigInteger.ONE;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i - 2].add(array[i - 1]);
    }
    System.out.println(array[n - 3] + "    " + array[n - 2]); // verify sum
    System.out.println(array[n - 1]);
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Also, please follow Java naming conventions. Method names start with a lower case letter, `Fibonacci` looks like a class name.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

You are running into numeric overflow. Use arbitrary precision arichmetics to fix this problem: replace `long[]` with `BigInteger[]`, and change formulas to method invocations, for example

```
array[0] = 1;
...
array[i] = array[i-2] + array[i-1];
```

becomes

```
array[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
...
array[i] = array[i-2].add(array[i-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this table](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html), the 92nd Fibonacci number is `7540113804746346429` and the 93rd is `12200160415121876738`.

The [range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of a Java `long` is `–9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`

Comparing the 93rd number in your Fibonacci sequence to the maximum value a `long` can take reveals what is happening:

```
9223372036854775807   -- max long value
7540113804746346429   -- 92nd number in Fibonacci sequence (works)
12200160415121876738  -- 93rd number in Fibonacci sequence (doesn't work)
```

You can consider using a `BigInteger` to store your sequence numbers instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the 93rd number is large than 2^63 - 1 (the largest possible long value in java). This means after the 92nd iteration the variable will overflow. If you want to use even larger number you should look into [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)